# List of edges starting from a set of vertices in a directed graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Let  g be a directed graph. Let  be A a set of vertices. How can I list all the edges which **start** from a vertex in A?

Answer (score 6):

The function [`EdgeList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeList.html) can take a pattern as a second argument,

```
g = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 
   1 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 
   2 \[DirectedEdge] 5, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 5}]
```

[image]

```
EdgeList[g, DirectedEdge[ 3, _]]
(* {3 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 5} *)
```

Note that this doesn't include the edges `1 \[DirectedEdge] 3` or `2 \[DirectedEdge] 3`, because they don't match the pattern.

And if `A` is a list of vertices, you just need to use `DirectedEdge[ Alternatives @@ A, _]` as your pattern.

Comment: It seems to work. Thanks very much Jason.

Answer (score 4):

If `G` is the graph,

```
SparseArray[UnitStep[IncidenceMatrix[G]]]["AdjacencyLists"][[A]]
```

lists the indices of the edges for each vertex in `A`.